# AngularJS cross domain error: Access has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I'm fairly new to AngularJs (I've only ever used Angular) and I'm trying to get some information from a domain other that the one my page is hosted in with a post request:

self.generateSession= function (bodyData) {

```
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST'
  };
  return $http.post('https://www.other-domain.com', bodyData, { headers: headers });
};
```

when I run this method I get this error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.other-domain.com' from origin 'my-page's-domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

is there anything I can do to fix the issue on the client side? (AngularJS) or is there something wrong with the server?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are **response** headers, never use response headers in a request, they only confuse things and guarantee pre-flight - though, your request will probably trigger pre-flight anyway since you're POSTing JSON ... does `www.other-domain.com` allow CORS?

Comment: `is there something wrong with the server?` nope, it just doesn't want you *borrowing* its resources from your web page - proxy the request through **your** server, since server->server is not hampered by CORS